# ¿aviso de cookies si solo uso la cookie de sesión de php?

Tags: php, cookies

Si no uso ningún script externo que pueda crear cookies como Google analytics, botones de facebook o twitter ni nada similar y la única cookie que se puede generar es la que usa PHP para el control de sesiones.

- ¿Es necesario definir una política de cookies?
- En caso afirmativo: ¿Es necesario la aceptación de la política de cookies por parte del usuario?

Entiendo que es una cuestión más legal que de programación, pero como seguro que muchos programadores no disponemos de asesoramiento legal para resolver este tipo de cuestiones estaría bien que nos echásemos una mano por estos foros.

Comment: No. Solo es necesario si son cookies analíticas, publicitarias o de seguimiento. Aquí puedes ver un pdf muy ilustrativo al respecto.
http://www.iabspain.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/INFOGRAFIA_COOKIES_IABLegal.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En el caso de usar sólo cookies de sesión no es necesario definir una política de aceptación de las mismas. Actualmente puedes encontrar toda la información en la web de la [Agencia Española de Protección de Datos (AEPD)](http://www.agpd.es/portalwebAGPD/index-ides-idphp.php), y más concretamente en la [Guía sobre el uso de las cookies](http://www.agpd.es/portalwebAGPD/canaldocumentacion/publicaciones/common/Guias/Guia_Cookies.pdf), proporcionada por la propia agencia.

En el **apartado 1** (Alcance de las normas) de la **sección II** de esta guía, se cita textualmente:

> Finalmente, con la finalidad de determinar el alcance de la normativa
>   y de esta guía es necesario señalar que quedan **exceptuadas** del
>   cumplimiento de las obligaciones establecidas en el artículo 22.2 de
>   la LSSI las cookies utilizadas para alguna de las siguientes
>   finalidades:
>
> - Permitir únicamente la comunicación entre el equipo del usuario y la red.
> - Estrictamente prestar un servicio expresamente solicitado por el usuario.
>
> En este sentido el Grupo de Trabajo del Artículo 29 en su Dictamen
>   4/20123 ha interpretado que entre las cookies **exceptuadas** estarían
>   aquellas que tienen por finalidad:
>
> - Cookies de «entrada del usuario»
> - Cookies de autenticación o identificación de usuario (únicamente de sesión)
> - Cookies de seguridad del usuario
> - Cookies de sesión de reproductor multimedia
> - Cookies de sesión para equilibrar la carga
> - Cookies de personalización de la interfaz de usuario
> - Cookies de complemento (plug-in) para intercambiar contenidos sociales

También puedes encontrar esta misma información en la web de la [Comisión Europea](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm).

**Actualización Diciembre 2018:**
Debido a cambios en la web de la Agencia Española de Protección de Datos (AEPD), el documento al que hago referencia en la respuesta ya no es accesible a través de ese enlace. La guía la podéis encontrar [aquí](http://www.interior.gob.es/documents/10180/13073/Guia_Cookies.pdf).